# upward 2cell in xypic in LyX

Tags: lyx, xy-pic

By default, the double arrow of a 2cell in `xypic` is downwards. How can I make it go upward in LyX?

I tried looking in the LyX documentation but wasn't able to figure out how to do it in LyX. I read somewhere that the TeX fix is to add a caret before the label, but it doesn't seem to work in LyX.

Comment: Can you add a small example of what you have done here please? (the TeX source I mean and a picture of the output?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that shows a normal two-cell, and then the second one with the central arrow reversed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\xyoption{2cell}
\UseAllTwocells
\begin{document}

\[
    \xymatrix@C=48pt{A\rtwocell & B}
\]

\[
    \xymatrix@C=48pt{A \rtwocell{^} & B}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You need to read [The XY Reference](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyrefer.pdf), page 44.

Comment: Dear Thruston, thanks for your answer! The caret does not work for me on LyX. I have written the exact same lines of code, but LyX compiles the second into an downward double arrow with a caret label.

Comment: OK - I am no expert at LyX, I will delete the answer when you get something better

Comment: You might want to ask on one of the mailing lists, https://www.lyx.org/MailingLists and post any useful answer here.